# Omron BP Monitor Custom Service and Characteristics bluettooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

Does anyone connect the latest Omron BP Monitor in Android programmatically? it's using custom characteristics for blood pressure. I found the service uuid and characteristics uuid but the measurement did not come I also enabled the notification